# Redux Epics: Type mismatch

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to sync my Firestore with Redux. I am using the following:

```
  redux: "^3.0.0"
  flutter_redux: "^0.5.0"
  redux_logging: "^0.3.0"
  redux_epics: "^0.9.0"
  rxdart: "^0.16.7"
```

When I try to add my epics to the middleware I get this error on this line of code:

```
final allEpics = combineEpics<AppState>([
    ordersEpic,
  ]);
```

> [dart] The element type '(Stream, EpicStore) → Stream' can't be assigned to the list type '(Stream, EpicStore) → Stream'.

[image]

**Epic:**

```
Stream<dynamic> ordersEpic(Stream<OrdersOnDataEventAction> actions, EpicStore<AppState> store){
  return Observable(actions)
  .ofType(TypeToken<RequestOrdersDataEventsAction>())
  .switchMap((RequestOrdersDataEventsAction requestOrders){
    return getOrders()
    .map((orders)=>OrdersOnDataEventAction(orders))
    .takeUntil(actions.where((action)=>action is CancelOrdersDataEventsAction));
  });
}
Observable<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getOrders(){
  return Observable(Firestore.instance.collection("orders").snapshots())
  .map((QuerySnapshot q)=>q.documents);
}
```

**Actions:**

```
class RequestOrdersDataEventsAction{}

class CancelOrdersDataEventsAction{}

class OrdersOnDataEventAction{ 
  final orders;
  OrdersOnDataEventAction(this.orders);
 }
```

**Orders:**

```
final ordersReducer = combineReducers<List<DocumentSnapshot>>([
  TypedReducer<List<DocumentSnapshot>,OrdersOnDataEventAction>(_setOrders)
]);

List<DocumentSnapshot> _setOrders(List<DocumentSnapshot> oldOrders, OrdersOnDataEventAction action){
  return action.orders;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a covariance problem.

```
typedef void myType(Stream<dynamic> s);

final list = List<myType>();

void myFunction(Stream<Order> s) {}
void myOtherFunction(Stream<dynamic> s) {}

// This gives the "(Stream<Order>) -> void not of expected type (Stream<dynamic>) -> void" error
list.add(myFunction);  
// This works
list.add(myOtherFunction);
```

Have you tried changing the type of your actions argument to dynamic?

```
Stream<dynamic> ordersEpic(Stream<dynamic> actions, EpicStore<AppState> store){
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried your suggestion before and led to the same error `The element type '(Stream<dynamic>, EpicStore<AppState>) → Stream<dynamic> can't be assigned to the list type '(Stream<dynamic>, EpicStore<AppState>) → Stream<dynamic>`

Comment: Any suggestion? :/

Comment: Not based on what I know. I would you be willing to take a look at the code if you can/want to share.

Comment: This is an empty project and I started by trying to sync my firstore with redux so I have included everything.

Comment: I just copied the code into my IDE and changed `Stream<OrdersOnDataEventAction>` to `Stream<dynamic>` in `ordersEpic`, and it compiled.

Comment: The error is not highlighted on Android Studio yes but the error appears in the console when I run it